# Format of EmailMessage.ccAddress

Tags: apex, email, fields

I'm writing an EmailMessage trigger for inbound emails and can't for the life of me find information about the format of the addresses in ccAddress. I need to parse the cc addresses. Using EmailMessage records in the system, System.debug() spits out addresses separated by a semicolon AND new line. I cannot email the system to confirm, but I'm trying to determine the following:

1. Does the field contain raw data from the email or does Salesforce format it in some way?
2. Is there a standard delimiter that can be expected?
3. Can the field contain a name along with the email address?

**Note:** This is about EmailMessage.ccAddress, not Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.ccAddresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got proper access to test this out. It appears that **EmailMessage.ccAddress** does NOT contain the raw cc data from the original message. It contains email addresses only, delimited by `;\n`. Test emails were sent from Gmail and Hotmail/Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

ccAddresses are set using a `List<String>`

When debugging the ccAddress each address will be separated by a ','

If you have email addresses with ';' or newline characters in them then you are not properly parsing the input used to create the list.

What are you using as the data entry portion to capture the ccAddresses? If it is a multiselect picklist you will need to spit the field by ';' to get the individual parts. If your users are adding the ';' same thing.

If there are newline characters you may nee to trim the input to remove any non characters from it.

Bottom line you will need to get is down to a clean `List<String>` of just the email addresses.

In addition, there should be no other info in the email address but the actuall address itself. I do not believe "John Jones " will work although some please correct me if I am wrong. You will have to parse that out as well.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm referring to EmailMessage.ccAddress which is a `String`, not Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.ccAddresses which is a `List<String>`. And this is an inbound email trigger. Sorry for the confusion. I'll clarify the question.